# How to add a local module to my anaconda path

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a module in my local directory ~/mglearn. How can I add it to my anaconda search path?  I did the following but it doesn't work:

```
In [9]: sys.path.append("/home/abigail/mglearn")
In [10]: import mglearn
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e19748f92cd9> in <module>()
----> 1 import mglearn

ImportError: No module named 'mglearn'
```

Comment: In Python, the directory name is the package name. You didn't show the directory structure, but try adding `/home/abigail` to the path. and then you can `import mglearn` if there is an `__init__.py` file in the `mglearn` directory. But the preferred way would be to make a `setup.py` file and then use `conda develop` or `pip install -e` to install the package.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referencing the `mglearn` library from the book *Introduction to Machine Learning with Python*. If that’s the case the library is available regularly through pip. You can use `pip install mglean` to add it to your anaconda search path.